# Adding names of samples/geentic donors to Seurat Object-demultiplexing

Tags: r, metadata, multiplexing, seurat

I have a relatively complex data set of 10x samples where Total-Seq barcodes have been used to map individual biological samples( 3-4 samples) per 10 sample.

The raw data are orgnized togehter in one seurat Object. The problem is code as it is now allows subseting of samples based on their nummeric position, and i would realy like to use "group_by_genetic donor" option for downstream analysis. It is essential.

Part of the code is like this:

```
explanatory<-readRDS("20220502_OVCA.rds")
table(explanatory@meta.data$orig.ident, explanatory@meta.data$hash.ID)
controls<-list(OVCA_4=c(1,2),OVCA_7=c(3), OVCA_11=(4),OVCA12=(2))
sMat<-sMat <- Reduce(cbind, lapply(names(controls), function(name) {
samples <- paste0("B-",(controls[[name]]))
seu@meta.data$orig.ident == name & seu@meta.data$hash.ID %in% samples
}))
flt <- apply(sMat,1,sum) > 0
sMat <- Reduce(cbind, lapply(names(controls), function(name) {
samples <- paste0("B-",(controls[[name]]))`
```

So this works but I end up with umap plot where als cells from controls are there but i can not say where is sample 4 from 10x sample 10.

I believe that I have to add metadata to seurat object explaining what is what. I tried generating CSV file listing  somethinkg like:

Sample 3  TrueSeq barcode (do I need a sequence here?) and sample name. After loading csv file I tried addMetaData function but it just does not work.
I believe CSV file is not organized correctly. I know that rownames have to be identical to rownames in Seurat object but not sure how to implement this.

I also tried simple:

```
 sobj$genetic_donors<-Donors$genetic_donor #Donors being the csv imported data frame
```

but it does not do the trick.

I have seen on some other places people are usinng `gsub` but I am not sure what to replace in original dataset.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If you want us to show you how to add metadata to a seurat object, it would help to have a seurat object to work with.  We don't have access to your data file.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: If you have already assigned the cells to donors, this might help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75931964/adding-donor-level-metadata-to-an-integrated-seurat-object/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75931964/adding-donor-level-metadata-to-an-integrated-seurat-object/)